# Implementing Viewpager2 in a fragment with Recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I'm trying to implement viewpager2 in a fragment which shows a list of notes with Recycler View. I tried different solutions but I'm unable to figure it out.

Here is my fragment_notes_list.xml :

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/notes_recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

list_item_notes.xml used to display recycler view viewholder:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_pertanyaan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#595959"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notes_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/notes_body"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notes_body"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notes_title" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Relevant snippets from fragment class NotesListFragment.kt :

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes_list, container, false)

        notesRecyclerView =
            view.findViewById(R.id.notes_recycler_view) as RecyclerView
        registerForContextMenu(notesRecyclerView)
        notesRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        notesRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        return view
    }

private inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fa: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {

        override fun getItemCount(): Int = NUM_PAGES

        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            return if (position == 0) {
                NotesListFragment()
       

 } else {
            CalenderFragment()
        }
    }
}



override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        notesListViewModel.notesListLiveData.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer { notes ->
                notes?.let {
                    Log.i(TAG, "got notes")
                    updateUI(notes)
                }
            })
    }

private inner class NotesAdapter(var notes: List<Notes>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesHolder>() {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotesHolder {
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_notes, parent, false)

           /* viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager)

            val pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this@NotesListFragment)
            viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter */

            return NotesHolder(view)
        }

        override fun getItemCount() = notes.size

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesHolder, position: Int) {
            val note = notes[position]
            holder.bind(note)
     



 }
    }
```

I'm confused should I add ViewPager2 with FrameLayout in list_item_notes.xml?
But then how can I implement ScreenSliderPagerAdapter for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

Since, I was unable to add Viewpager with recycler view of NotesListFragment, I made another Parent Fragment with viewpager and put NotesListFragment inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to have 2 fragments: list and calendar and thats why you need to implement ViewPager2. Your NotesListFragment looks good. You have recyclerview with notes there, but what you want now is to provide list of NotesListFragment and CalendarFragment which will be scrollable in left/right direction. First, extract ScreenSlidePagerAdapter  outside of your fragment code. Next you have to add ViewPager2 to your parent activity/fragment

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And then in your parent activity/fragment pair it with adapter like this way:

```
val viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager)
val pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this)
viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
```

You can read more about this in official docs: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have extracted ScreenSlidePagerAdapter outside of fragment code. I want to add ViewPager2 to fragment_notes_list.xml which is displaying only a recycler view. Simply adding ViewPager2 class to it would not work. So, how should I add it? Should I put Recycler View and ViewPager2 in a Frame Layout?

Comment: You should have NotesListFragment and CalendarFragment which you want to paginate. I don't know your CalendarFragment but in NotesListFragment you have recycler view with fragment_notes_list.xml as items. I assume you are currently hosting NotesListFragment in some kind of parent activity or fragment. You should add the viewpager2 to that parent activity/fragment, NOT the child fragments or the recycler item layout.

Comment: NotesListFragment is hosted inside Main Activity. But if I add viewpager2 to main activity then it kind of overlaps viewpager in all the child fragments that I have created which is not what I want. I want the swiping feature only on NotesListFragment.

Comment: So you want to have each recycler item representing a note that you can switch to calendar?

Comment: basically, I want to have a list of notes in one fragment and a calendar in another. A user should be able to swipe horizontally between notes list and calendar. The calendar has no relation to saved notes as such.

Comment: Then you should do as I said before: use viewpager2 in your main activity to host both fragments. You should have main activity with only the viewpager2 in layout. In main activity code you should bind your viewpager with adapter as in my original answer. Now you should be able to swipe between notes and calendar easily. If not please post a video or screenshots so I can better understand what you are getting

Answer (score 0):

I had tried implementing ViewPager in Main Activity earlier also. But this way i cannot close viewpager fragments since they are always visible. How do I get around this?

here is my main activity after the changes you suggested:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
NotesListFragment.Callbacks {
    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager)
        val pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this)
        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
}

override fun onNotesSelected(notesId: UUID) {
        val fragment = NotesFragment.newInstance(notesId)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
    }

    fun onNotesDeleted(notes: Notes) {
        val fragment = NotesListFragment()
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .commit()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Note Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

mainactivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pager"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

here are some screenshots,

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13ITZqcaeDeydCe0tW2Iu7VoSGSZnrlkg?usp=sharing

Comment: ScreenSlidePagerAdapter and Main Activity both are calling NotesListFragment that's why it's overlaping.

Comment: Upload image in stackover flow easy to view user